# Typescript Abstract Class Method Access Derived Class Property

Tags: oop, typescript, inheritance, abstract

```
abstract class MyClass() {
    protected static foo: Array<number>;

    protected static doWorkOnFoo(): void {
        let x: number = 0;

        for (let f of | what goes here? this? self?|.foo) {
            x = x + foo;
        }
    }
}
```

When implementing an abstract class, and wanting derived classes to have a static property and a static method that operates on those properties, how would one access those in the abstract class so that the derived class can just use that method?

I know this can be worked around by just setting a default value on the static property and using `this`, but this sparked my interested and I'm curious to know if there's some way to access generic derived class or something from an abstract class in TS.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

While I wasn't able to find exactly what I was looking for (see comments), a workable solution is to change the signature of the `doWorkOnFoo()` method to the following:

```
protected static doWorkOnFoo(): (typeof MyClass) => void;
```

Since it is already an abstract class it can take a derived class as an argument and then reference the derived class's static properties.

Comment: It should be `this`. in a static context `this` refers to the class and not the instance.

Comment: But in this context `this` is referring to the abstract super class, not the derived class that will actually be using the function. Unless I'm sorely mistaken.

Comment: Depends, from the ts point of view you're right, but in runtime (js point of view) it will be the actual derived class. In your example there's no need to know which class it is, it's enough that it's `MyClass`.

Comment: Yes, but that seems..."incorrect" haha. The proper OOP desire in me is preventing me from being ok with that, even though it's totally acceptable.